# Why is this almost affine code not equivalent to a linear code?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, coding-theory, matroids

I am a bachelor student who just started studying coding theory and I came across the following example in "Generalized Hamming weights for almost affine codes" by Johnsen and Verdure, page 4 (https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.01504):

> We will use a running example throughout this paper. It is the almost affine code C
> ′
> in [14, Example 5]. It is a code of length 3 and dimension 2 on the alphabet F = {0, 1, 2, 3}. Its set
> of codewords is

> $$
> \begin{matrix}
> 000 & 011 & 022 & 033 \\
> 101 & 112 & 123 & 130 \\
> 202 & 213 & 220 & 231 \\
> 303 & 310 & 321 & 332 \\
> \end{matrix}
> $$

> [...] This is an example of an almost affine code which is not
> equivalent to a linear code, and not even to a multilinear code.

I understand why the code is almost affine. However, to me, it seems like this is a linear code, since all the codewords can be expressed as linear combinations of 101 and 011. What mistake am I making? Also, how would I check that it is not equivalent to a multilinear code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: When people say a $C$ linear code, they mean that $C$ is linear subspace of a vector space over a finite field. It is true that $C'$ is a sub-__group__ of the group $(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)^3$, generated by the two group elements $(1,0,1)$ and $(0,1,1)$, but since it is not a sub-**space** of a vector space, we cannot call $C'$ linear. Note that $\mathbb Z/\mathbb 4Z$ is not a field.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you for your help. I think I understand it now.

Comment: @MikeEarnest: That looks like an answer to me – see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35479.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When people say a $C$ linear code, they mean that $C$ is linear subspace of a vector space. It is true that $C'$ is a sub-*group* of the group $(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)^3$, generated by the two group elements $(1,0,1)$ and $(0,1,1)$, but since it is not a sub-**space** of a vector space, we cannot call $C'$ linear. Note that $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ is not a field.

I do not know about how to prove it is not equivalent to a (multi)linear code, perhaps someone else can answer about that.

Comment: Does this imply that it is in general not possible to construct a linear code on the alphabet {0, 1, 2, 3}?

Comment: @AsocialButterfly It is possible, just not using usual addition/multiplication $\pmod 4$. You just need to define $+$ and $\times$ operations on $\{0,1,2,3\}$ which turns it into a field, and then use a vector space and subspace over that field. Just choose an arbitrary bijection of $\{0,1,2,3\}$ with $\mathbb F_4$. The latter can be defined as $(\mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z)[x]$, where $x$ satisfies $x^2=x+1$.

Comment: Linear codes over rings are most certainly a thing, and in that context often *linear (over $R$)* = *a submodule of the free module $R^n$*. I guess the authors here want to discuss some aspects, where it makes a difference whether we have a (commutative) ring as opposed to a field.